# HAProxy "Uptime" Checking

Tags: haproxy

I'm using HAProxy 1.3.15 in a cluster, behind which I have a couple servers running IIS7 (Win2k8). Occasionally, when I check the "Status", I see that the amount of time "UP" has reset. Nothing I can see on the server indicates any sort of failure or resets, but I still find it odd.

So, I guess I have 2 questions:

1. How does HAProxy determine if a
   server is "UP" for the purposes of
   reporting?
2. How reliable is that
   uptime information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "uptime" is how long the server has been up since haproxy last pulled it out of rotation.

So if you have a few checks in a row that are above a certain response time, the uptime is reset.

These checks are define by the check options when defining a `server`:

> check
>
> This option enables health checks on
>   the server. By default, a server is
>   always considered available. If
>   "check" is set, the server will
>   receive periodic health checks to
>   ensure that it is really able to serve
>   requests. The default address and port
>   to send the tests to are those of the
>   server, and the default source is the
>   same as the one defined in the
>   backend. It is possible to change the
>   address using the "addr" parameter,
>   the port using the "port" parameter,
>   the source address using the "source"
>   address, and the interval and timers
>   using the "inter", "rise" and "fall"
>   parameters.

So the "few checks" are controlled by:

```
fall <count>

The "fall" parameter states that a server will be considered as dead after <count> consecutive unsuccessful health checks. This value defaults to 3 if unspecified. See also the "check", "inter" and "rise" parameters.
```

The response time or timers are controlled by `inter`:

> The "inter" parameter sets the
>   interval between two consecutive
>   health checks to  milliseconds.
>   If left unspecified, the delay
>   defaults to 2000 ms. It is also
>   possible to use "fastinter" and
>   "downinter" to optimize delays between
>   checks depending on the server state :
>
> Server state   Interval used Up 100%
>   (non-transitional)     "inter"
>   Transitionally up (going down)
>   Transitionally down (going up), or yet
>   unchecked  "fastinter" if set, "inter"
>   otherwise Down 100%
>   (non-transitional)     "downinter" if
>   set, "inter" otherwise Just as with
>   every other time-based parameter, they
>   can be entered in any other explicit
>   unit among { us, ms, s, m, h, d }. The
>   "inter" parameter also serves as a
>   timeout for health checks sent to
>   servers if timeout check is not set.
>   In order to reduce "resonance" effects
>   when multiple servers are hosted on
>   the same hardware, the health-checks
>   of all servers are started with a
>   small time offset between them. It is
>   also possible to add some random noise
>   in the health checks interval using
>   the global "spread-checks" keyword.
>   This makes sense for instance when a
>   lot of backends use the same servers.

More at http://code.google.com/p/haproxy-docs/wiki/ServerOptions .

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? What d'you mean by "a few checks in a row"?

Comment: Links busted too now.